# Show message if record already exists

Tags: codeigniter

I am newbie in **CodeIgniter**. I created a method that insert record in mysql db table now to    make the query stop if record with same name already exists so I wrote:

```
public function set_project()
    {
        // If project name already exists?
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT pro_id FROM projects WHERE pro_name = '".$this->input->post('pro_name')."'");

        if ( sizeof($query->row_array()) == 0) {

            $data = array(
                'is_featured' => $this->input->post('is_featured'),
                'pro_type' => $this->input->post('pro_type'),
                'pro_name' => $this->input->post('pro_name'),
                'pro_client' => $this->input->post('pro_client'),
                'pro_loc_city' => $this->input->post('pro_loc_city'),
                'pro_loc_state' => $this->input->post('pro_loc_state'),
                'pro_yr_start' => $this->input->post('pro_yr_start'),
                'pro_yr_end' => $this->input->post('pro_yr_end'),
                'pro_loc_cur' => $this->input->post('pro_loc_cur'),
                'pro_size' => $this->input->post('pro_size'),
                'pro_size_cat' => $this->input->post('pro_size_cat'),
                'pro_size_units' => $this->input->post('pro_size_units'),
                'pro_desc' => $this->input->post('pro_desc')
            );

            return $this->db->insert('projects', $data);

        } else {
            return "Already exists";
        }
```

which works fine but who can I show message to my view?

Comment: is `pro_name` a unique field in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I did it, actually I have to move that check in controller.

Answer (score 0):

you are writing `return "Already exists"`, but to see the output change that code to `echo '<script>alert("Already exists!")</script>';` instead.